# Eddystone beacon scanning using React native framework

Tags: swift, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, eddystone

I'm relatively new to react native. I could not find any solution for scanning Eddystone packet broadcasting beacons in react native framework. Please suggest me for the same. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Existing projects on github don't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on a React-Native prototype using Eddystones beacons. The prototype runs on an Android OS, but this library also has support for iOS. Try it out — [react-native-kontaktio](https://github.com/Artirigo/react-native-kontaktio)

I hope this will help you.